# Exchange Certificate Issue

Tags: exchange-2003, ssl-certificate, isa-server

We recently signed up to a 3rd party hoster for filtering spam emails. It required blocking at the ISA firewall and only allowing port 25 in and outbound, also with setting relays to their subnetts for mail in exchange.

After that our certificates don't seem to work on PDA devices. I don't know anything other than how to find the certificate on the Exchange server, and install it onto devices. Why would this problem be happening? On a HTC Touch Dual, running Windows 6.0, the error code: 0x80072F17 comes up when trying to sync mail over the air.

Windows Server 2003, Exchange Server 2003 and ISA 2004.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspecting that if you have really set your ISA to only allow the SMTP ports in and out, that that would be the cause of your problem, rather than the OWA certificates.

In order for the HTC Touch Dual (or any Windows Mobile Device) to work, it needs to access your Outlook Web Access virtual server, which could be proxied by your ISA server, or runing directly on your Exchange box (you would know which). For this to work, you need at least port 80 (for HTTP) and 443 (for SSL) open.

I am assuming you are using SSL only, else you would not be asking about certificates, so have a looksee at that ISA server and make sure that you have not inadvertently blocked tcp/443 to the OWA site.

You can also use a regular browser from your local Starbucks (or your house) and go to https://<your.owa.website&gt; and see if it works.